# Usage of Same Explicit App ID for two apps

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning, app-id

Can I use same explicit app id for my iPhone & iPad applications? This App ID is configured to use Push notification, so I can receive push on both apps. Will appstore allow this? I couldn't find any useful information about this particular scenario.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same App Id in 2 apps, *unless* it's a single, universal app. That is, an app that is built and designed to run well on both an iPhone and an iPad. I would recommend creating a universal app. That way you have a single App Id and an app that runs on both device types.

Comment: You're right I should have created universal, but I have created two separate apps. Will apple allow this or what you are saying (i.e. You cannot use the same App Id in 2 apps) is just the recommendation.

Comment: Well, I guess we should be clear. If you create, in iTunesConnect, 2 apps, they will each have a unique app id, assigned by Apple. No way around that. I assume you are talking about this app id. On the other hand, there is the Bundle Id, e.g. com.company.myapp, where "myapp" is the unique part for your app. Although there would be nothing stopping you from using "myapp" in 2 apps, I think when you tried to submit the second app containing "myapp" as it's bundle id, it'd get rejected by the automatic verification that happens during upload. (That's just a guess, but it makes some sense to me.)